# How can I batch convert a directory of subfolders, maintaining similar filestructure for the output

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, mp4

Right now I am converting using the following in Command Prompt:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('dir /b /s *.mp4') DO (ffmpeg -i "%G" -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 30 -b:v 0 -b:a 128k "%~nG.webm" & del "%~G")
```

However, this spits out all output files into the top level of the directory. I'd like the outputs to be sent to their original subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

#### I'd like the outputs to be sent to their original subdirectories.

You need to change `"%~nG.webm"` to `"%~dpnG.webm"` to include the directory `d` and path `p`.

See [Parameters / Arguments - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)